# How to center an image in the header?

Tags: html, css, image, center

So this is what i have Tried, which doesn't work.
    Ive also tried to make it a block and then margin that as 0 auto, like other questions say, but that doesn't help at all...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

<style>

.logo {
text-align: center;
}

</style>

</head>

<header> 

<div id="logo">  
  <img src="logo.png">
</div>

</header>


</html>
```

I just cannot seem to center this image, and i would like to in as little lines as possible.

Comment: change `.logo` to `#logo`. a `.` is for a class, and `#` is for an ID.

Comment: Is your div the width of the page? If not, maybe try `#logo {width: 100%;}` (Also, the `.logo` selector matches `class="logo"`, so it currently won't match your div.)

Comment: Adding 100% fixed it! thanks!

Comment: Great, glad it worked!

Comment: Did you include all of your html/css? You shouldn't have to specify `width: 100%` on a block level element. Your code works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxxydW

Comment: Don't edit your question to have [SOLVED] in the title. Click the check mark next to the answer that answered your question, and the system shows it for you. Also, don't fix the code in your question. Leave it in the broken state.

Comment: sorry! i'm just really new. i will make it better.

Comment: nvm you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need # for id . is used for class

```
    #logo{
      text-align:center;
     }
```

**Edit**

Answered in comments above

Comment: If you did get the solution from the comments and posted it as an answer, it's courteous to either give attribution or mark your answer as community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to add the **body tag** and do not make mistakes between id and class.

Comment: I won't,  i was just replicating the problem so I pulled it out of the body of my project.

Comment: @Andrew Li, I tested her code. I mean the last version of her code cause she edited it.